# Why does SSMS apply syntax highlighting to the word level?

Tags: sql, ssms

When using SSMS to author SQL scripts the word level is highlighted as though it is a keyword in the language. I can't find it in the list of documented keywords.
[Reserved Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Why does SSMS apply syntax highlighting this case? Is there something else about the word level that is special in a SQL statement.

I am using it as a column name.

Comment: It's in the ODBC Reserved Keywords table on the same page as you link. (Though admittedly so is "SECTION" and that doesn't get the highlighting)

Comment: Unfortunately, the highlighter for SSMS isn't very sophisticated. It works on a per-word basis. So for any multi-word statement that might warrant highlighting (say `set transaction isolation level ...`), each word is individually set up to receive highlighting. Similarly, when the same word can appear in multiple contexts where *different* colouring may be warranted, they basically have to toss a coin and pick one colour to use.